# Dereferencing a String Vector in C++ when passing to GTK callback

Tags: c++, vector, callback, gtk

I have this code which is trying to pass a vector to a callback function:

```
static void displayvecchoices( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer   data ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vecp = *(std::vector<std::string> *)(data);
    std::cout<<"vec: "<<vecp[0]<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *display;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_dialog_new ();
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
    gtk_window_fullscreen (GTK_WINDOW(window));

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.push_back("1");

    display = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Display");
    g_signal_connect_swapped (display, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (displayvecchoices), &vec);
    gtk_widget_set_can_default (display, TRUE);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (GTK_DIALOG (window)->action_area), display, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_grab_default (display);
    gtk_widget_show (display);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

When the button display is clicked, I get an error of 'bad alloc' and the program crashes.

When I try this:

```
std::vector<std::string>* vecp = (std::vector<std::string> *)(data);
std::cout<<"vec: "<<(*vecp)[0]<<std::endl;
```

It prints out vec: but no element and the size is said to be 18446744073706420840 of the vector.

Comment: Is the original vector `vec` still in scope and alive then the callback is called? It haven't gone out of scope or been destructed?

Comment: Definitely hasn't been destructed. How would i check out of scope? Those are the only statements with vec in the code. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude updated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks, your callback arguments are swapped:

- you should either use `g_signal_connect_object` instead of `g_signal_connect_swapped` or
- change `displayvecchoices` declaration to

  ```
  static void displayvecchoices(gpointer   data, GtkWidget *widget)
  ```